# LOAD DATA INFILE easily convert YYYYMMDD to YYYY-MM-DD?

Tags: mysql

Hi I have an INFILE I want to import, but the dates are of the form :

```
AADR,20120403,31.43,31.43,31.4,31.4,1100
AAU,20120403,2.64,2.65,2.56,2.65,85700
AAVX,20120403,162.49,162.49,154.24,156.65,2200
```

Is there any easy way to convert the dates to be '2012-04-03' without having to do something like open it first with a perl script, convert the dates, and then writing the file back out again?

TIA !!

Comment: Try to use STR_TO_DATE function.

Comment: yeah this worked : SELECT STR_TO_DATE('20130105','%Y%m%d');  so I guess that would mean importing into a table as STR then running the STR_TO_DATE() into another table that is of type DATE?  be nice if I could do the STR_TO_DATE() within the INFILE command..

Comment: LOAD DATA INFILE statement allows doing this in one command. Have a look at tombom's answer.

Comment: Have you tested it? I wouldn't have expected that it would need to be converted if the target is a DATE type (will need converted for a DATETIME/TIMESTAMP)

Comment: From the reference - STR_TO_DATE() returns a DATETIME value if the format string contains both date and time parts, or a DATE or TIME value if the string contains only date or time parts.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This loads and converts in one step, no need for another table. For more information see the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html).

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.txt'
INTO TABLE t1
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
(column1, @var1, column3, ...)
SET column2 = STR_TO_DATE(@var1,'%Y%m%d')
```

Comment: Yeah I got it to work!  thx.  trick was figuring out where to put the "FIELDS SEPARATED BY" clause.  It's clunky to past stuff in the comment box, but command was :

Comment: LOAD DATA INFILE '/home/kensey/history/AMEX_20120403.txt'
into table extract_bcp_import                                                  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
(symbol, @var1, openp, high, low, last, volume ) set tdate = STR_TO_DATE(@var1, '%Y%m%d');

Comment: Can't see your command, but I happened to edit my answer anyway :) Was testing it now to be sure.