# break down the large number of rows in CSV and process them as a batch wise php

Tags: php, mysql, csv, import

I am upto edit and upload a CSV with more then 50000 records (shopping cart produts). and it should update the number of tables in the system. So i m using zend framework with my shopping cart.

im planing to break them down  (50000 CSV records) in memory before processing them batch-wise using PHP/MYSQL

please any one can give me advice on this

What im up to now is

```
public function getDataFromPath($path=null) {
        if($path == null) {
            $path = $this->_path;
        }
        ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", 1);
        $fp = fopen($path, "r");
        while(($line = fgetcsv($fp, 5000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            $line = self::trimArray($line);
            $this->data[] = $line;
        }
        fclose($fp);          
        return $this->data;
    }
```

regards
roshan

Comment: Why? Really, why would you want to do this? And why would it update the number of tables?

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck? Read a little, write a little, rinse, repeat until the file is processed...

Comment: @tombom actually i want update my all products and its attributes once via CSV file as i have large number of records 50,000 i plan to break it down in memory and porcess batch wise

Comment: I update with currently im upto stuff thanks for comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every RDBMS out there shouldn't have problems with 50.000 rows. That's nothing. There's no need to process them batch wise.

Just use the [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) command and you will be fine.

For an example see here: [LOAD DATA INFILE easily convert YYYYMMDD to YYYY-MM-DD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10102167/load-data-infile-easily-convert-yyyymmdd-to-yyyy-mm-dd)

**UPDATE** (cause of comment to Ion Wood's answer): To create a CSV file you can use the `SELECT .. INTO OUTFILE` command.

```
SELECT a,b,a+b INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/result.txt'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM test_table;
```

For more info, see the [manual.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select-into.html)

Comment: @Roshan Updated my answer. Is that what you are looking for? If not, please clarify more.

Answer (score 1):

This is a job for...

DATABASE MAN!!!

Load your csv directly into a table using the [load data infile](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) business and do what ever magic you need to after that.

Comment: thanks but i should give a customer interface to do it export csv edit and upload