# Importing a large number of custom posts into wordpress from a csv file

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, performance, csv

I am having an issue with my script that imports entries from a csv file and inserts them as wordpress custom posts (each row is a single post)...
Initially, I set up the import functionality in its own class and that was barely working...from what I gathered, the issue was that the global variables are not cached and each time I called the instance more memory would be consumed until the process ran out of memory and crashed out... so I removed the class and set up the import functionality as described by the code below.

With this set up, I got to the point where it works fine with up to 17k posts, but if I try to import more posts than that, it just drops out without any errors (no errors are reported in my php error log or the wordpress debug.log files)

the script successfully inserts 17k posts  printing out the echo information up to the point where it stops prematurely at "XXX items remaining" and it finishes loading the page outputting nothing more at that point... it never makes it to the final `echo "Done!";` statement...

This happens on both localhost development environment and on a hosted development server.
I kept my eye out on the memory usage, and it never exceeds 60% on my localhost(starts out at ~50%) and I do not see a stepwise memory climb indicating memory leakage...

I've also attempted to use ini_set('memory_limit', '64M'); and set_time_limit(0);

From what I've read on some other similar questions regarding this,

- for SQL 20k entries should not be a big deal
- wordpress should be able to handle this as well if the server is
  powerful enough

What kind of optimizations/improvements can I do to the code below to make this script work on this scale?

or perhaps skipping the wordpress built in functionality and processing everything with LOAD DATA INFILE as mentioned by fancypants [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10119442/break-down-the-large-number-of-rows-in-csv-and-process-them-as-a-batch-wise-php)

I would prefer to process the data via the provided wordpress functionality.

The csv file is ~1mb...

the code:

---

these functions reside in their own file - import.php

```
function fileupload_process() {
  ini_set('memory_limit', '64M');
  set_time_limit(0);
  $uploadfiles = $_FILES['uploadfiles'];
  if (is_array($uploadfiles)) {
    foreach ($uploadfiles['name'] as $key => $value) {
      // look only for uploaded files
      if ($uploadfiles['error'][$key] == 0) {
        $filetmp = $uploadfiles['tmp_name'][$key];
        if (($handle = fopen($filetmp, "r")) !== FALSE) {
          $flag = true;
          $songs = explode("\n",file_get_contents($filetmp));
          $count = count( $songs );
          unset($songs);
          echo "Total item count: " . $count . "<BR />";
          // typical entry: If You Have To Ask,Red Hot Chili Peppers,0:03:37, Rock & Alternative,1991,on
          // using a generous 1000 length - will lowering this actually impact performance in terms of memory allocation?
          while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            // Skip the first entry in the csv containing colmn info
            if($flag) {
                      $flag = false; 
              echo "<BR />"; 
              $count--; 
              continue; 
            }
            // insert the current post and relevant info into the database
            $currently_processed = process_custom_post($data, $count);
            $count--;
          }
          echo "Done!";
          fclose($handle);
        }
        unlink($filetmp); // delete the temp csv file
      }
    }
  }
} // END: file_upload_process()
function process_custom_post($song, $count) {
  $track =  (array_key_exists(0, $song) && $song[0] != "" ?  $song[0] : 'N/A');
  $artist = (array_key_exists(1, $song) && $song[1] != ""  ?  $song[1] : 'N/A');
  $length = (array_key_exists(2, $song) && $song[2] != ""  ?  $song[2] : 'N/A');
  $genre = (array_key_exists(3, $song) && $song[3] != ""  ?  $song[3] : 'N/A');
  $year = (array_key_exists(4, $song) && $song[4] != ""  ?  $song[4] : 'N/A');
  $month = (array_key_exists(5, $song) && $song[5] != ""  ?  $song[5] : 'N/A');
  $playlist = (array_key_exists(6, $song) && $song[6] != ""  ?  $song[6] : '');
  $custom_post = array();
  $custom_post['post_type'] = 'songs';
  $custom_post['post_status'] = 'publish';
  $custom_post['post_title'] = $track;
  echo "Importing " . $artist  . " - " . $track . " <i> (" . $count ." items remaining)...</i><BR />";
  $post_id = wp_insert_post( $custom_post );
  $updated = update_post_meta($post_id, 'artist_name', $artist);
  $updated = update_post_meta($post_id, 'song_length', $length);
  $updated = update_post_meta($post_id, 'song_genre', $genre);
  $updated = update_post_meta($post_id, 'song_year', $year);
  $updated = update_post_meta($post_id, 'song_month', $month);
  $updated = update_post_meta($post_id, 'sample_playlist', $playlist);
  return true;
} // END: process_custom_post()
function import_page () {
//HTML for the import page + the file upload form
  if (isset($_POST['uploadfile'])) {
    fileupload_process();
       }
}
```

---

the import.php is included in a wordpress plugin outside of the plugin's class

ie here's the relevant info on how I get the script on the import page:

```
define( 'MY_PLUGIN_ROOT' , dirname(__FILE__) );
include_once( MY_PLUGIN_ROOT . 'import.php');
class my_plugin () {
 function __construct() {
  add_action( 'init', array( &$this, 'admin_menu_init' ) );
 }
 function admin_menu_init() {
   if(is_admin()) {
     //Add the necessary pages for the plugin
     add_action('admin_menu', array(&$this, 'add_menu_items'));
   }
 }
 function add_menu_items() {
  add_submenu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=songs', 'Import Songs', 'Import Songs',  'manage_options', 'import-songs', 'import_page' );
 }
}
```

---

any thoughts, comments or recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Only thing i can see to reccommend is to get your count in the while loop instead of reading the whole file then exploding it to get the count. also it seems like youre only using the counter to output it for human readability. Whenever I do big imports i only echo at the end, maybe a couple lines, outputting 20k lines to the screen could be another problem.

Comment: I took out all the echo statements out, except for the final echo 'Done!';,  I omitted the count file explosion and implemented it within the loop...it's still not importing all the posts, stops at ~17K...however, I am getting a 500 Internal server error now, even though my provider's server log files are completely devoid of any errors whatsoever?? I'll attempt to do this on localhost as I have more oversight available and hopefully I'll see if I can track down the issue that is causing this....

Comment: No luck, localhost exits without errors like before...thanks for the suggestions anyways

Comment: are you taking original posts from local/remote db, or is csv file your only source of post data. if you have access to db, just dump tables to sql files

Comment: the uploaded csv is the only source of data

Comment: I wonder if there isn't a problem with the file around line 17k?

Comment: no no problems with the csv files...I updated my answer and findings regarding this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So after a long profiling session, with XDEBUG, phpmyadmin and friends, I finally narrowed down what the bottleneck was: the mysql queries

I enabled

`define('SAVEQUERIES', true);`

to examine the queries in more detail and I output the queries array to my debug.log file

```
global $wpdb;
error_log( print_r( $wpdb->queries, true ) );
```

upon examining each INSERT call to the database

1. wp_insert_post()

   [0] => INSERT INTO `wp_posts` (`post_author`,`post_date`,`post_date_gmt`,`post_content`,`post_content_filtered`,`post_title`,`post_excerpt`,`post_status`,`post_type`,`comment_status`,`ping_status`,`post_password`,`post_name`,`to_ping`,`pinged`,`post_modified`,`post_modified_gmt`,`post_parent`,`menu_order`,`guid`) VALUES (...)

   [1] => 0.10682702064514
2. update_post_meta()

   [0] => INSERT INTO `wp_postmeta` (`post_id`,`meta_key`,`meta_value`) VALUES (...)

   [1] => 0.10227680206299

I found that each one of those calls to the database costs, on average, ~0.1 s on my localhost server

But, since I am updating 6 custom fields per entry, it works out to

6 cf insert calls/entry * ~0.1s/cf insert call *20 000 total entries * 1 min/60s = 200 min

~2.5 hrs to process the custom fields alone for 20k posts

Now, since all the custom fields are inserted into the same table, wp_post_meta, I looked to combine all the update_post_meta calls into one call, and hence, drastically improve the performance in terms of the execution time of this import script.

I looked through the update_post_meta function in the wp core and saw there was no native option to pass an array  instead of a single cf key and value, so I went through the relevant code to pinpoint the SQL INSERT line and looked how to do something along the lines of:

```
`INSERT INTO `wp_postmeta` (`post_id`,`meta_key`,`meta_value`) 
  VALUES ( $post_id,  'artist_name' , $artist) 
         ( $post_id,  'song_length' , $length )
         ( $post_id,  'song_genre' , $genre ) ...`
```

and so forth for all the 6 custom fields in my case, all rolled in inside a single `$wpdb->query();` .

Tweaking my process_custom_post() function to reflect this, I ended up with:

```
function process_custom_post($song) {
  global $wpdb;

  // Prepare and insert the custom post
  $track =  (array_key_exists(0, $song) && $song[0] != "" ?  $song[0] : 'N/A');
  $custom_post = array();
  $custom_post['post_type'] = 'songs';
  $custom_post['post_status'] = 'publish';
  $custom_post['post_title'] = $track;
  $post_id = wp_insert_post( $custom_post );

  // Prepare and insert the custom post meta
  $meta_keys = array();
  $meta_keys['artist_name'] = (array_key_exists(1, $song) && $song[1] != ""  ?  $song[1] : 'N/A');
  $meta_keys['song_length'] = (array_key_exists(2, $song) && $song[2] != ""  ?  $song[2] : 'N/A');
  $meta_keys['song_genre'] = (array_key_exists(3, $song) && $song[3] != ""  ?  $song[3] : 'N/A');
  $meta_keys['song_year'] = (array_key_exists(4, $song) && $song[4] != ""  ?  $song[4] : 'N/A');
  $meta_keys['song_month'] = (array_key_exists(5, $song) && $song[5] != ""  ?  $song[5] : 'N/A');
  $meta_keys['sample_playlist'] = (array_key_exists(6, $song) && $song[6] != ""  ?  $song[6] : '');
  $custom_fields = array();
  $place_holders = array();
  $query_string = "INSERT INTO $wpdb->postmeta ( post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES ";
  foreach($meta_keys as $key => $value) {
     array_push($custom_fields, $post_id, $key, $value);
     $place_holders[] = "('%d', '%s', '%s')";
  }
  $query_string .= implode(', ', $place_holders);
  $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare("$query_string ", $custom_fields));
  return true;
}
```

and viola! Instead of 7 INSERT calls to the database per custom post, I end up with 2 making a gynormous difference when attempting to process multiple custom fields while iterating over a large number of posts - in my case now, 20k entries are processed to completion within 15-20min (vs a situation where I would experience a dropout after ~17k posts and a few hrs of processing time)...

So the key thing I learned from this whole experience,

mind your database calls - they can quickly add up!