# How to load date data in MySQL when using LOAD DATA

Tags: mysql, datetime, import

The default date format of a date column is `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` in MySQL.

The data file that I am trying load from has a date field that has the date in `DD-MON-YY HH:MM:SS` format. When I load this file using `LOAD DATA` command, the database gets confused and just makes all date entries to `0000-00-00 00:00:00` or NULL

Here is the test I did using `STR_TO_DATE` option and it doesn't work.

**Test infile (test_temp.csv)**

```
c1, c2
07-JUN-12 22:50:19, "abc"
07-JUN-13 22:50:19, "bcd"
```

**Test table (temp_test)**

```
describe temp_test;
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| c1    | datetime    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| c2    | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

**Data Load command:**

```
load data
infile '/var/lib/mysql/DataSet-1/temp_test.csv'
ignore
into table temp_test
fields terminated by ','
enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '\r\n'
ignore 1 lines
(@var_c1,c2)
set c1 = STR_TO_DATE(@var_c1,'%d-%b-%y %h:%i:%s');
```

**Output**

```
Query OK, 2 rows affected, 2 warnings (0.00 sec)
Records: 2  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

MySQL> show warnings;
+-------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level | Code | Message                                                                 |
+-------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Error | 1411 | Incorrect datetime value: '07-JUN-12 22:50:19' for function str_to_date |
| Error | 1411 | Incorrect datetime value: '07-JUN-13 22:50:19' for function str_to_date |
+-------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+

MySQL> select * from temp_test;
+------+------+
| c1   | c2   |
+------+------+
| NULL | abc  |
| NULL | bcd  |
+------+------+
```

Is the problem with

1. Input date column (Should it be `07-JUN-12` or `07-Jun-12`) or
2. With my format string (`%d-%b-%y`) or
3. Something else?

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10102167/load-data-infile-easily-convert-yyyymmdd-to-yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: I am sorry the link you gave does not solve the problem. I created a small test to show the problem:

Answer (score 25):

Your format string for `STR_TO_DATE()` is invalid. Hours in your sample data have 24-hour format (`%H` or `%k`) instead of 12-hour (`%h`). You can see all possible date format specifiers [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

Change

```
%d-%b-%y %h:%i:%s
```

to

```
%d-%b-%y %H:%i:%s
         ^^
```

Your statement might look like this

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/temp_test.csv'
IGNORE INTO TABLE temp_test
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' -- or '\n'
  IGNORE 1 LINES
(@c1, c2)
SET c1 = STR_TO_DATE(@c1,'%d-%b-%y %H:%i:%s');
```

After loading with your sample data

```
mysql> select * from temp_test;
+---------------------+------+
| c1                  | c2   |
+---------------------+------+
| 2012-06-07 22:50:19 | abc  |
| 2013-06-07 22:50:19 | bcd  |
+---------------------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Looks like we need to include all columns in round brackets along with date column with set command. Is there any way we can escape spaces in the column names? I can't seem to put quotes there.

Answer (score 11):

Since I had a similar problem, but the incoming date format was different, here is what you would do should your incoming date format be the following,

Sample input date format,

```
Tuesday, May 24, 2016
Wednesday, May 25, 2016
```

You would need to use a different date format,

```
%W, %b %d, %Y
```

Here is a link to the [mysql documentation](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-date_format-function.php) and a [list of date formats](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/MySQL/0280__Date-Time-Functions/STRTODATEstrformat.htm), but briefly,

Date part,

```
%Y Year, numeric, four digits
%y Year, numeric (two digits)
%c Month, numeric (0..12)
%m Month, numeric (00..12)
%M Month name (January..December)
%b Abbreviated month name (Jan..Dec)
%d Day of the month, numeric (00..31)
%e Day of the month, numeric (0..31)
%D Day of the month with English suffix (0th, 1st, 2nd, 3rd, ?-)
```

Weekday,

```
%W Weekday name (Sunday..Saturday)
%a Abbreviated weekday name (Sun..Sat)
%w Day of the week (0=Sunday..6=Saturday)
%j Day of year (001..366)
```

Time

```
%T  Time, 24-hour (hh:mm:ss)
%r  Time, 12-hour (hh:mm:ss followed by AM or PM)
%H  Hour (00..23)
%h  Hour (01..12)
%I  Hour (01..12)
%k  Hour (0..23)
%l  Hour (1..12)
%i  Minutes, numeric (00..59)
%S  Seconds (00..59)
%s  Seconds (00..59)
%f  Microseconds (000000..999999)
%p  AM or PM
```

There are other patterns which are not listed above.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/temp_test.csv'
IGNORE INTO TABLE temp_test
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' #use '\n' for linux
  IGNORE 1 LINES
(@var_col1, col2)
SET col1 = STR_TO_DATE(@var_col1,'%d-%b-%y %H:%i:%s');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/temp_test.csv'
IGNORE INTO TABLE temp_test
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' -- or '\n'
  IGNORE 1 LINES
(@c1, c2)
SET c1 = IF(CHAR_LENGTH((@c1)) = 0, NULL, (CONCAT(SUBSTRING(@c1e,7,4),SUBSTRING(@c1,3,4),SUBSTRING(@c1,1,2),SUBSTRING(@c1,11,9))));
```

Comment: Its not clear how this would convert 'JUN' into -06-?