# Date and time in MySql

Tags: java, mysql

If I have a string,

```
2016-02-24T18:12:24-0500
```

Can it be directly stored in MySql as a Datetime or Timestamp, or should it be split into two columns before loading and stored as Date and Time.

When retrieving data from database, I need to sort the record set based on date and time. If it is possible store as one datetime, can it be used to directly sort records retrieved?

I will use this in Java and JPA programs.

Edited:

I have a text file to be prepared like this:

```
1 A 2016-02-24T18:12:24-0500
2 B 2016-02-25T18:12:24-0500
3 C 2016-02-26T18:12:24-0500
```

Then I am going to use this statement to load data to database:

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'data.txt' INTO TABLE UserData

Can this be directly loaded into the database table UserData?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a single field with both parts or two fields really depends on what you are going to do with the information afterwards.

If you are going to do sorting normally it will be easier if you just use one field.

Your String needs to be converted to a Java object before storage. Just convert it to a java.sql.Timestamp before sending to the database.

Comment: please see my added post.

Comment: If you are going to load with Mysql Load Data function you will need to do the conversion there. I have no experience with that load tool but a few searches here show that it is possible to use a str_to_date conversion. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18927249/how-to-load-date-data-in-mysql-when-using-load-data