# How to create a table with a specific txt file?

Tags: mysql, sql

The file I am trying to load looks like this: `/04:2016:27/$/06,54,05/$/Page/$/Bob/$/24/$/Bax/$/Reper 10/`

I receive the error

> Error Code: 1292. Incorrect datetime value: '' for column 'data_achizitie' at row 1

```
create table Tabela_veche(
    data_achizitie date,
    numere varchar(255),
    nume varchar (255),
    prenume varchar(255),
    bucati int,
    unit_mas varchar(255),
    reper varchar(255),
    fulldate datetime);
```

AND

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 
    'C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 8.0\\Uploads\\fisier.txt'
    INTO TABLE Tabela_veche
    CHARACTER SET latin1
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY '/'
    OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '$'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

Please help!
Thanks!

Comment: date expect a format of yyyy-mm-dd and this is not what you have in your file

Comment: ?Thank you! I know that, but do you know how to solve this

Comment: Have a look at Input Preprocessing section in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html - in your case assign the data column to a variable and format it before writing to table.

Comment: You need to edit the field before inserting into database. After that you can process it to display in whatever format you require

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18927249/592355 ..and https://stackoverflow.com/a/10102707/592355, welcome

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Input Preprocessing section in dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html - in your case assign the data column to a variable and format it before writing to table.
And you lines terminated and optionally enclosed by are the wrong way round. NOTE the str_to_date function. (basically any sql function is available in the set statement).

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 
    'C:\\Program Files\\MariaDB 10.1\\data\\sandbox\\data.txt'
    INTO TABLE Tabela_veche
    CHARACTER SET latin1
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY '$'
    OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '/'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
(@dt,   
    numere,   nume,  prenume ,    bucati ,  unit_mas ,    reper  ) 
     set data_achizitie = str_to_date(@dt,'%m:%Y:%d')
;
```

BTW you aren't supplying fulldate in the data so you need to specify which columns you are loading.

```
+----------------+----------+------+---------+--------+----------+----------+----------+
| data_achizitie | numere   | nume | prenume | bucati | unit_mas | reper    | fulldate |
+----------------+----------+------+---------+--------+----------+----------+----------+
| 2016-04-27     | 06,54,05 | Page | Bob     |     24 | Bax      | Reper 10 | NULL     |
+----------------+----------+------+---------+--------+----------+----------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```