# Importing csv file into phpMyAdmin, converting varchar to proper types

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, phpmyadmin

I hope you can understand my question from the title.

I have a days.csv file, which includes the following tablenames

meter_id,date,meterstand

Which stores data like this:

1122,15/03/2013,458

The importing goes fine, but once imported the data types aren't good. The meter_id gets converted to an INT, which is fine. But the date gets converted to VARCHAR and the meterstand gets converted to decimal(9,4). I want the date table to be DATE and the meterstand to be an INT as well. Is there a quick fix for this? I have to run queries based on dates, which would be a lot easier if the date was actually a DATE type.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know this isn't exactly what you asked, but have you considered creating table with correct types and then using load data infile from a mysql prompt. It is the fastest way to get csv into MySQL.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The 'meterstand' data is now an INT, but the date shows as 00-00-0000, as I already expected. Is there a way to convert dates written as 00/00/0000 to 00-00-000?

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10102167/load-data-infile-easily-convert-yyyymmdd-to-yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: Still doesn't work.. I might be doing something wrong though. This is the query I'm running:

LOAD DATA INFILE 'days.csv'
INTO TABLE days
fields terminated by ','
enclosed by '"'
(meter_id,@var1,meterstand)
SET date = STR_TO_DATE(@var1,'%Y%m%d');

But I still get the date as 00-00-0000..

Comment: Yeah I just realized that after posting. But even `%Y%m%d` to `%d%m%Y` it doesn't work. The data type for the date column is DATE btw, as I think it should be..