# Mysql change date format mm/dd/yy into yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: mysql

Hi can someone help me how I can change **mm/dd/yy** into **yyyy-mm-dd** in mysql?

My date table is in VARCHAR so that when I import the csv,
it can be copy but the date in csv is in mm/dd/yy and like Aug. 1, 1992,
I want both format to be in yyyy-mm-dd. Thanks.

Comment: You should not store your date as character. Use a datetime format.

Comment: I try to make it date format but when I upload my csv. it gives me 0000-00-00 and not the date that I want.

Comment: Never, ever store dates in a `varchar` column. Just don't

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10102167/load-data-infile-easily-convert-yyyymmdd-to-yyyy-mm-dd) for an example

Comment: I second the advice of never storing dates in text columns. Format and conversion issues should be solved when you import/load the data from your external data source (and this may require some temporary table with text columns, depending on the conversion technique you use)... but just to fix the data so as to save it in an appropriate data type column. And this goes for integers, floats, social security numbers... anything that may require formatting, validation or whatever ;)

Answer (score 0):

user your mysql date column as DATETIME , at the time of importing CSV use this script to change the format

```
<?php

     $CSVFormat = $variabletostorecvsformat;
     $CSVTimestamp = strtotime($CSVFormat);
     $MysqlCompatibleFormat = date(Y-m-d,$CSVTimestamp );

 ?>
```

Now insert the varibale to the database