# Is this the best format of CSV file for importing into a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, bash, csv

I have data in the following format (sample data, there are many rows):

```
"Rec Open Date","number 1","number 2","Data Volume (Bytes)","Device Manufacturer","Device Model","Product Description"
"2015-10-06","0427","70060","137765","Samsung Korea","Samsung SM-G900I","$39 option"
"2015-10-06","7592","55620","0","Apple Inc","Apple iPhone 6 (A1586)","some text  #16"
...
```

what I want to know is, what is the best format/practice for importing this into mysql?

Some specific questions are:

1. Should the date be "2015-10-06"
2. Should columns 2, 3, and 4 be in string format with double quotes e.g. "0427"
3. For the column headers, should I remove all the spaces and the brackets
4. Anything else

maybe my data would be better looking like this before importing it into my database:

- Replace all spaces with underscore
- remove brackets
- turn columns 2, 3, and 4 into values by removing the double quotes

which would look like this:

```
"Rec_Open_Date","number_1","number_2","Data_Volume_Bytes","Device_Manufacturer","Device_Model","Product_Description"
"2015-10-06",0427,70060,137765,"Samsung Korea","Samsung SM-G900I","$39 option"
"2015-10-06",7592,55620,0,"Apple Inc","Apple iPhone 6 (A1586)","some text  #16"
...
```

Again just looking for best practice out there.

The next question will be is there a parser that can do all this, maybe in bash or other equivalent?

Comment: a CSV file should be in the exact order of how you would export data. The data from the export should be same as import for the csv data.

Comment: so you would import as is then, without making any changes?

Comment: you should make the db changes on the db; not on the csv.

Comment: how do i do that? just to be clear. do I import as is, and then make the changes(name changes etc.) in the db, not sure I quite follow...

Answer (score 0):

You can do the job with `mysql load data infile` from the command line as described here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html

If you have control over the format of the csv file, any values that will load into numeric database types should not have quotes. The date values are fine for mysql DATE type as you have shown them. If you are stuck with that csv format, you can use the load data options to convert input values as described here: [LOAD DATA INFILE easily convert YYYYMMDD to YYYY-MM-DD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10102167/load-data-infile-easily-convert-yyyymmdd-to-yyyy-mm-dd) The example is about date conversion, but many other conversions are possible.

Also note that, if your db table is already defined, you can skip the header row so no need to worry about the headings matching column names and spaces, etc.

Answer (score 0):

1.One way to do this is by importing the csv file into mysql, you can use tools like phpMyAdmin.

2.You can try this code. Its a php script to convert the file to mysql.

```
<?php    
$databasehost = "localhost";
$databasename = "test";
$databasetable = "sample"; 
$databaseusername="test"; 
$databasepassword = "";
$fieldseparator = ",";
$lineseparator = "\n";
$csvfile = "filename.csv";
if(!file_exists($csvfile)) {
die("File not found. Make sure you specified the correct path.");
}
try {
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$databasehost;dbname=$databasename", 
    $databaseusername, $databasepassword,
    array(
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE => true,
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
    )
);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
die("database connection failed: ".$e->getMessage());
}

$affectedRows = $pdo->exec('
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ".$pdo->quote($csvfile)." INTO TABLE `$databasetable`
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ".$pdo->quote($fieldseparator)."
  LINES TERMINATED BY ".$pdo->quote($lineseparator))." ');
echo "Loaded a total of $affectedRows records from this csv file.\n";
?>
```

3.You can use any framework or tool to do so.

Comment: get an error on line27 `LINES TERMINATED BY ".$pdo->quote($lineseparator));` ---  Syntax error or access violation: 1148 The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version

Comment: There was a small error that i edited in that line. You can try now.

Comment: If there is still a problem then try putting the exec string into a statement first and use variables.

Comment: try this as well:


Use --local-infile=1 argument on the mysql commandline:

When you start MySQL on the terminal, include --local-infile=1 argument, Something like this:

mysql --local-infile=1 -uroot -p

mysql>LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/foo.txt' INTO TABLE foo 
COLUMNS TERMINATED BY '\t';
Then the command is permitted:

Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 3  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0