# How do I convert month name in string to short month

Tags: mysql, date

I'm trying to load in a csv file into my database and need to invoke a function that converts the date string, which is currently in the dd-mmm-yyyy format, into the yyyy/mm/dd format.

I've tried this but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE("10-Aug-2017", "%M %d %Y");
```

Comment: In which language are you parsing your csv file ?

Comment: Can you please show the code you are currently using?  This might be less of a MySQL thing and more of the thing in the language you are using.

Comment: I'm using the LOAD DATA INFILE sql statement to upload a csv dataset into a mysql database. I know that i can invoke a user-defined function on my database as part of this process but I need a function that will convert the existing string into a valid date format. So this is all being done in MYSQL (using mysql workbench) as opposed to, for example, a php script

Comment: does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10102167/load-data-infile-easily-convert-yyyymmdd-to-yyyy-mm-dd help you ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for mysql you can use str_to_date() for convert a string in date

```
    select str_to_date('23-08-2018', 'd%-m%-%Y') 
    from dual
```

then you you have a proper date value

and you can show a date value using date format

```
   select date_format( my_col_date, '%Y/%m/%d')
   from dual 


   select date_format(str_to_date('23-08-2018', 'd%-m%-%Y'), '%Y/%m/%d')
   from dual
```

In your case

```
   select date_format(STR_TO_DATE("12-Aug-2017", "%d-%b-%Y"), '%Y/%m/%d')
   from dual
```

see this refer for mask parameters https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Assuming your insert table contain  col1, col2, col3, .... col4 
and col1 si column for date values 
for load infile  you should convert your date as

```
    LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/your_file.csv'
    IGNORE INTO TABLE temp_test
      FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
      LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' #use '\n' for linux
      IGNORE 1 LINES
    (@var_col1, col2, col3, ......, coln)
    SET col1 = STR_TO_DATE(@var_col1,'%d-%m-%Y');
```

Comment: Thanks I've edited my question. I've tried the str_to_date function but doesn't work for me

Comment: what mean  doesnt't work ?  you have error .. show the error message .. wrong result show the actula result and the expected  result  ..

Comment: answer update ...  the select is for query and not for LOAD INFILE  .. i have a suugestion for INFILE too

Answer (score 0):

Apologies... I misunderstood the function. It's now working:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE("12-Aug-2017", "%d-%b-%Y");
```

Returns 2017-08-12